# SitecoreItem.Visualization.Layout throws exception

Tags: events

I created a new screen in sitecore and added a button. On clicking of this button I am calling a method. Everything works fine except following piece of code.

```
if (sitecoreItem.Visualization.Layout != null) 
    {
    // code
    }
```

sitecoreItem.Visualization.Layout is throwing 
StackTrace:

> "   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Request()\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.UIUtil.IsWebkit()\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.UIUtil.SupportsInlineEditing()\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.SetDisableWebEditEditing(String value)\r\n 
>   at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext..ctor(SiteInfo siteInfo, Boolean
>   processQueryString)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String
>   name)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.PreviewLinkBuilder.ResolveTargetSite(Item
>   item)\r\n   at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.GetPreviewSiteContext(Item
>   item)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.ResolveContextDevice()\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.get_Layout()"

But when I call the same method from a Sitecore Agent it is working fine. Is there any configuration settings I am missing here?

Updated:
It is an anchor link

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success js-import
                                        <%# ((TargetLanguage)Container.DataItem).LanguageTranslatedStatus.ToLower() == "delivered" || ((TargetLanguage)Container.DataItem).LanguageTranslatedStatus.ToLower() == "approved" || ((TargetLanguage)Container.DataItem).LanguageTranslatedStatus.ToLower() == "in_review" ?  "" : "disabled" %>"
                                        data-projectid="<%= Project.ProjectId %>" data-lang="<%# Eval("LanguageCode") %>">Import
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
                                    </a>
```

call to the method

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static object ImportLanguage(string projectId, string lang)
        {
            try
            {
                var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService();
                return sitecoreService.ImportLanguage(projectId, lang);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Full Stack:

```
Failed to import language {"Message":"Request is not available in this context","StackTrace":" at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Request()\r\n at Sitecore.UIUtil.IsWebkit()\r\n at Sitecore.UIUtil.SupportsInlineEditing()\r\n at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.SetDisableWebEditEditing(String value)\r\n at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext..ctor(SiteInfo siteInfo, Boolean processQueryString)\r\n at Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String name)\r\n at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.PreviewLinkBuilder.ResolveTargetSite(Item item)\r\n at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.GetPreviewSiteContext(Item item)\r\n at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.ResolveContextDevice()\r\n at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization.get_Layout()\r\n at xxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx(String itemGuid, String lang) in E:\\MyFolder\\xxxx.xxx.xxx\\xxx\\SitecoreService.cs:line 643\r\n at xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.SitecoreService.ImportLanguage(String projectId, String lang) in E:\\MyFolder\\xxxx.xxx.xxx\\xxx\\SitecoreService.cs:line 785\r\n at xxxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.ImportLanguage(String projectId, String lang) in E:\\MyFolder\\xxxx.xxx.xxx\\xxxxx\\ProjectDetails.aspx.cs:line 83","ExceptionType":"System.Web.HttpException"}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, your `[WebMethod]` doesn't run in the context of a Sitecore Site. The reason it works when run from an Agent is; it runs in the context of the `"scheduler"` site.

You can force a site context, with this change:

```
using (new SiteContextSwitcher("website") {
    var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService();
    return sitecoreService.ImportLanguage(projectId, lang);
}
```

But it isn't the best or most flexible approach. Likely someone can outline a better example.

Further reading: [Correctly switching Sitecore contextes](https://ctor.io/correctly-switching-sitecore-contextes/)